# Is there a way to change the menu link color through css?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to edit the menu colors on https://demo-nefeli.skarpeti.gr/

"ΕΜΕΙΣ", "ΥΠΗΡΕΣΙΕΣ" and " Η ΟΜΑΔΑ ΜΑΣ" have anchors to homepage. Since they include the 'https://demo-nefeli.skarpeti.gr/' in the link the template identify them as current page and set the color of the links to blue.

Is there any way to fix this using `css`?

I'm trying the following with no luck:

```
.current-menu-item  a {
    color: black; !important
    
}
```

Comment: From the admin panel go to your menus. Expand the links you want to exclude and you will notice a field to type additional class. If you dont see it go to the top right corner and from screen options under Show advanced menu properties check CSS Classes. So for example you can add class exclude and your css rule should look like .current-menu-item:not(.exclude)  a { var(--primary-color) }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the semicolon after the important tag:

```
.current-menu-item  a {
    color: #000 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me they are blue because of "color: var(--primary-color);" rule in style.css.

Either way, you can use the [:visited pseudoclass to style the visited links.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited)

and !important should be inside the semicolon (black !important;)